# Is there a standard siphoning hose size?

Tags: equipment

We have a hose that fits some of our equipment (bottle filler wand) but it is loose on both the racking cane and auto siphon. Is there a standardized size for this equipment or does it vary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, there are three common sizes: **3/8"**, **1/2"**, and **1"**.

Racking equipment commonly uses 3/8" tubing. This will, of course, vary by brand, but I've found that most of the equipment I've ever used requires 3/8" tubing. 1/2" is less common but still easy to find.

1" tubing is often used for blow-off tubes since it fits easily into most glass carboys and provides enough space for blow-off gunk so that it doesn't clog.

Answer (score 1):

I expect someone with more experience will answer your question outright, but in the mean-time, you might want to consider a hose clamp:

[image]

Available (via google) from some homebrew stores, or any hardware store.
http://www.bittercreekhomebrew.com/Small-Hose-Clamp-pr-289.html

Answer (score 1):

I've always had problems with air bleeding in between hose and racking cane. Nice way to get oxidation. I used to always wrap electrical tape around it tight - but that's a PITA. I then tried a standard hose-clamp like the one above and couldn't get a good seal.

I'm now going to try one of these little guys

[http://www.amazon.com/Snapper-Ratchet-Closure-Nominal-351--394/dp/B0015HOOSQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015HOOSQ)

Comment: Good idea. I was thinking a zip-tie would also work

Comment: It's very difficult to get a good seal with certain types of hose.  A hose clamp is best combined with a hose barb, and softer plastics like vinyl will seal better than plastics like polyethylene.